# jQuery .val() is undefined on onChange event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
function ddlList_Changed() {
    var ddlList = jQuery('select[name*="ddlList"]');
    var value = jQuery(ddlList).val();
    alert(value);
}
```

The above shows an alert displaying 'undefined' whenever the dropdownlist's selection is changed.

I've read around other scenarios were .val() has been undefined and suggestions were that the .val() needed to be called *after* the document is ready/has been fully loaded - but surely this is well past that stage anyway with it being only fired on selection changed?

NOTE: ddlList is not null, it initially selects it without any problems. The .val() seems to be the issue.

Comment: (a)  `ddlList` is already a jQuery object, no need to pass it to jQuery again (it's equivalent to  `jQuery(jQuery('select[name*="ddlList"]')).val()`) (b) Does such an element exist? (c) *edit*: `ddList` will **never** be null, since `jQuery` **always** returns a jQuery object (but it might not contain any elements).

Comment: How many selects do you have containing the name `ddlList`?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: @FelixKling - I thought it needed writing like that as .val() was a jQuery function?

Comment: @Rocket - it's assigned to the onChange attribute in code-behind (C#) on PageLoad.

Comment: @DeeMac: `ddlList` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @Rocket - understood. I'm new to jQuery so didn't realise it was structured that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
     var ddlList = $('select option:selected').val();
     alert(ddlList);                   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please supply code examples (relevant HTML, JavaScript event code etc) so that we can see where the error is. Because it's not the selection change event or val() function that is wrong.

Also, you probably shouldn't rewrap the ddlList in a jQuery object over and over again.

Also note that when the event handler is called on an element that element is assigned to the `this` variable - no need to find it using a jQuery selector again.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RCLjy/5/

Comment: I'm going to take your approach of wiring the event handler up that way instead of code-behind....

Comment: I think that's a good way to go - I have never liked the idea of mixing WebForms code-behind with JavaScript event wiring. Especially when it's so easy with jQuery. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Yer I agree, having code-behind tell client-side script to handle an event felt dodgy - I'm still gettin used to what jQuery is capable of. Your answer's helped me here mate, thanks a lot. Problem solved. (I'll mark as answer when it lets me).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/39hwp/

All you need is:

```
$('select[name*="ddlList"]').change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());     
});
```